# Bringing PyMySQL cursor to beginning

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I am using PyMySQL 0.7.9 with MySQL 5.1.73. I have to do two operations using the same PyMySQL cursor. After first operation is complete on the cursor, I need to bring the cursor back to the beginning.

```
import pymysql;

cursor.execute("my query");
# First operation
for row in cursor :
  # run update query to update status flag for all rows fetched.

# Second Operation
for row in cursor : 
  # run some more commands for the rows.
```

I added

```
cursor.rownumber = 0
```

before the second operation. It worked. But is there any PyMySQL function by which I can achieve the same?
Is there anything similar in PyMySQL to http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

Comment: You can use `Cursor.scroll (0, mode='absolute')`. It will literally do the same as `cursor.rownumber = 0` (because that is what will be executed inside that function).

Comment: cursor.scroll worked. Thanks alot @Solarflare . Please put this as answer. I will select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the API definition, you can use the [`scroll`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#scroll) function:

> **`cursor.scroll(value [, mode='relative' ])`**
>
> Scroll the cursor in the result set to a new position according to mode .
>
> If mode is *relative* (default), value is taken as offset to the current position in the result set, if set to *absolute*, value states an absolute target position.

So to jump to the first row, you can use

```
cursor.scroll(0, 'absolute')
```

Internally, `pymysql` will actually just execute `cursor.rownumber = 0` too.

This will only work with a normal `cursor`, not with the unbuffered `SScursor`, where you (currently) can only scroll forward.